# How to print anonymous hash of hashes

Tags: perl

I am trying to print anonymous hash of hashes but not getting desired output

```
$hash = { 
           name => { 
               nitesh => mine, 
               ankush => yours
           }, 
           Company => { 
               XYZ => mine, 
               other => sector_32
           }
};


foreach $key (sort keys %$hash) {
    print "\n key is $key";
    foreach $key2 (sort keys %{$hash=>{$key}}) {
        print "\n key2 is $key2";
    }
}
```

Getting output as

```
 key is Company
 key2 is Company
 key is name
 key2 is name
```

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;`Always put that at the top of your code

Comment: You should always use indentation to make your code easier to read and avoid simple syntax errors. I fixed it for you this time. See how much easier it is to read?

Comment: Also, note that with the fat comma operator `=>` the left hand argument will automatically be quoted, if it is not already quoted. I.e. `foo => 1` will become `"foo" => 1`. But the right hand argument will not be quoted, it will be a so called "bareword", which *may* be treated as a string, unless its name conflicts with a reserved word. So you need to quote that part, if it is a string: `foo => "bar"`.

Answer (score 5):

You are using a `=>` to get the keys of the inner hash, when you should be using a `->`. Remember to quote the values of your hashes and to add `use strict; use warnings;` to the top of your script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $hash = { 
    name => {nitesh => 'mine', ankush => 'yours'}, 
    Company => { XYZ => 'mine', other => 'sector_32'} 
};


foreach my $key (sort keys %$hash) {
    print "key is $key\n";
    foreach my $key2 (sort keys %{$hash->{$key}}) {
        print "key2 is $key2\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
key is Company
key2 is XYZ
key2 is other
key is name
key2 is ankush
key2 is nitesh
```

Comment: @Nitesh References [arrow operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator) and [comma operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator). It's worth to mention that `%{$hash->{$key}}` can be written as `%{$$hash{$key}}` as well, though `->` makes it more clearer.